# How to use IdentityServer to authorize a WebApi in .NetCore using JWT tokens?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, jwt, identityserver4

I'm developing a microservice application to manage the authorization and authentication of my users to the webapi routes of other microservices already developed. After researching the best option, I found out that IdentityServer4 do exactly what I need, but I need to use MongoDB as my database and I couldn't make it work.

How do I configure my application to work as a server for authenticate others using MongoDb?

The idea is:

1. I want my user to consume a login route on my authorize server and, if successful, receive a JWT token as response.
2. The user then uses the JWT token as a Header to consume my APIs on the other services already developed.
3. The service receives the JWT token and then validates it on my authorize microservice to see if user has permission to consume the API.

I used the project eShopOnContainers as my base reference: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers, and using this library https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore I can generate a JWT token and login in the project, but can't make it work with a different project using IdentityServer.
Also tried following this samples https://github.com/souzartn/IdentityServer4.Samples.Mongo but most of them are old and the code doesn't work anymore.

This is what I could do till now. This code generates the JWT token and is able to authorize and authenticate perfectly on the authentication project.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    var mongoSettings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MongoDbSettings));
    var settings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MongoDbSettings)).Get<MongoDbSettings>();

    services.AddSingleton<MongoDbSettings>(settings);

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    var signingConfigurations = new SigningConfigurations();
    services.AddSingleton(signingConfigurations);

    var tokenConfigurations = new TokenConfigurations();
    new ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<TokenConfigurations>(
        Configuration.GetSection("TokenConfigurations"))
            .Configure(tokenConfigurations);
    services.AddSingleton(tokenConfigurations);

    services.AddAuthentication(authOptions => {
        authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(bearerOptions => {
        var paramsValidation = bearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters;
        paramsValidation.IssuerSigningKey = signingConfigurations.Key;
        paramsValidation.ValidAudience = tokenConfigurations.Audience;
        paramsValidation.ValidIssuer = tokenConfigurations.Issuer;

        // Verify if token signature is valid
        paramsValidation.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true;
        // Verify if token hasn't expired
        paramsValidation.ValidateLifetime = true;
        // Define tolerance time to token lifetime
        paramsValidation.ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero;
    });

    // Create policy to use Token as Authorization method
    services.AddAuthorization(auth => {
        auth.AddPolicy("Authorized", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());
        auth.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
        auth.AddPolicy("Manager", policy => policy.RequireRole("Manager"));
    });
}
```

SigningConfigurations.cs

```
public class TokenConfigurations
{
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public int Seconds { get; set; }
}

public class SigningConfigurations
{
    public SecurityKey Key { get; }
    public SigningCredentials SigningCredentials { get; }

    public SigningConfigurations() {
        using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)) {
            Key = new RsaSecurityKey(provider.ExportParameters(true));
        }

        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(Key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature);
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific error or blocker are you getting?

Comment: i personally wouldn't touch indetityserver4 with a 10ft pole due to it's complexity. have a look at [JWTSimpleServer](https://github.com/Xabaril/JWTSimpleServer) which is way easier to use.

Comment: @cheesemacfly I ran into a lot of them, the closer I got from making it work throw me an error 500 - the server actively refused the connection.

Comment: @RyanGunner IdentityServer4 is an implementation of oidc and oauth2 [specifications](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/specs.html). It discourages the use of the password flow, the only flow supported by JWTSimpleServer. You really can't compare the two. Actually, I wouldn't use JWTSimpleServer in a microservices environment.

Comment: @LeonardoDias `500 - the server actively refused the connection` most likely means that the port uses a different protocol (http vs https)